# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. Don't know why happens

Tags: python, max, valueerror, is-empty

When I compile it this error appears. ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence.

```
ag_averaged = [max(a_g[i_averaged[i]:i_averaged[i+1]]) for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1)]
```

Honestly I have no idea why this ocurrs

Comment: Please tag with a programming language!

Comment: **python 3.7, I'm using it on Spyder**

Comment: can you share the code segment?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, it's because the sequence that you passed to `max` has zero length. In your case, `i_averaged[i]` might be equal to `i_averaged[i + 1]` on some occasion, which gives a slice of length zero. To prevent it from raising an exception, you can provide a default value for the `max` function:

```
max(a_g[i_averaged[i]:i_averaged[i+1]], default=None)
```

Now it returns `None` when the list is empty. Of course, it might not benefit you as the maximum value of a list of zero length might not be meaningful in your application. It is now your responsibility to ensure that the value makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Pls add load() after importing the library